# Appending 5 divs at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code runs below so that the correct div is appended to the page when I click the '.show-more' button. I want to be able to append 5 of these divs every time I click this button, but not sure how to do that?

HTML

```
<div class="content-section news-preview clearfix">
    <div class="title">Title of News Article</div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="images/news_sample208x135.jpg" width="208" height="135">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Dui luctus lectus eget libero volupat, a tempor velit malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mattis egestas lorem a sodales.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="article-link">http://www.lintothenewsarticle.com/news/article/title-of-news-article</a>
</div>
<!-- /content-section -->
<div class="show-more-container">
    <div id="content-news-container"></div>
    <button class="btn show-more">Show 5 More</button>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.show-more').click(function() {
    var contentNews = $('div.content-section:last').prop('outerHTML');

    console.log("contentNews", contentNews);

    $('#content-news-container').append(contentNews).slideDown(slow);
});
```

Comment: Does you need the 5 times to be a variable so you can alter the value to get different append length?

Comment: I'm not sure why don't just use a simple for loop ?

Comment: `var contentNews = $('div.content-section:last').prop('outerHTML'); $('#content-news-container').append(contentNews)` Are you just adding cloned content? And so do you really want to add 5 times the same content? Question isn't clear imho, you should provide sample to replicate your issue with all relevant code

Comment: Wouldn't calling `$('#content-news-container').append(contentNews)` 5 times append the div 5 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a loop and clone the `DIV` five times:

```
$('.show-more').click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var contentNews = $($('div.content-section:last')[0].cloneNode(true));
        $('#content-news-container').append(contentNews).slideDown('slow');
    }    
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ToddT/364y88af/

**EDIT:**

As was pointed out, using a `DocumentFragment` is the more efficient way to do this sort of manipulation:

```
$('.show-more').click(function () {
    var contentNews = $('div.content-section:last').prop('outerHTML');
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      frag.appendChild($(contentNews).get(0));
    }

    $('#content-news-container').append(frag).slideDown(slow);
});
```

Per @Travis Kaufman's answer.

Comment: that seems a bit inefficient as it will synchronously trigger layout 5 times.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks! Is there a way to modify the code so that it can only add 5 divs at a time until 20 are present (Max of 20 'content-section' on a page)?

Comment: @Travis Kaufman, sure it could be optimized-- I'm just laying out the general idea.

Comment: @sk_225, in your function, you can check how many of those `content-section` elements there are and skip the loop if there are already 20.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) to append all of the elements in one go in an efficient manner

```
$('.show-more').click(function () {
    var contentNews = $('div.content-section:last').prop('outerHTML');
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      frag.appendChild($(contentNews).get(0));
    }

    $('#content-news-container').append(frag).slideDown(slow);
});
```

EDIT: fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sc5585x7/

Comment: I really guess OP doesn't want to add 5 times the same content on page, because that doesn't really make sense. But i'm aware you are answering question as asked :)

Comment: Yeah in theory you could easily modify the code to add any arbitrary content; the point I was going for was to emphasize using DocumentFragment instead of cloning a node and appending inside a loop.

Comment: Using a document fragment is definitely better-- I was just giving an example that showed how to use a loop to create multiple copies. Depending on the situation, though, it might not make much of a difference in actual performance. Still, it is better.